# How do you initialize a class function that can be set as a default array and take input/output as an array?

Tags: c++, xcode

I am supposed to be using a class "field01". "field01" has input and output functions for an array of size int 7. In the main function there is a default field01 and I can't seem to find a way to make my field01 function agree with the default initialization. (It seems like I can't get field01 to read as an array) I am new so please be patient with the beginner and potentially bad code!

The class I have formed a constructor as....field01(){};....field01(int p[7]){}; .....field01(p){};...field01(int p[]){} all having a private member of the class "int p[7]"

```
class field01{public: field01(){};//...input, output and overload+ functions here 
private:
int p[7];};
```

...

```
int main(void)
{field01 a(0,1,2,3,4,5,6);
return 0;}
```

The code will not compile. I get an error message "no matching constructor for initialization of 'field01'" that lights up the field01 declaration in the main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have no constructor that has 7 `int`s. You only have 1 constructor that has 0 arguments.

If you want the class to accept 7 parameters like that, you'll need to make a special constructor for it. That will look something like the following:

```
class field01 {
    public:
    field01(int i1,int i2,int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7) {
        p[0] = i1;
        p[1] = i2;
        p[2] = i3;
        p[3] = i4;
        p[4] = i5;
        p[5] = i6;
        p[6] = i7;
    }
};
```

Comment: Or you could use `field01(std::initializer_list<int> my_ints)`. And you should really use the initialization list to initialize members rather than the constructor body.

Comment: @JesperJuhl True. The only problem is I'd have to know how to use them. The compiler I use is old and doesn't support them. I haven't played with them in things like [onlinegbd](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) enough to get my feet wet with them yet. Feel free to add an example if you like.

Comment: `And you should really use the initialization list to initialize members rather than the constructor body.` True, when possible. I'm not really sure how to do that here, though, with an array like this. Again, feel free to add an example if you like.